# I'm not able to publish JSON message with SSL(TLS) as kafka producer from C#

Tags: c#, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I'm getting an error when i try to publish my JSON message with SSL(TLS) to kafka topic asynchronously.

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "bootstrap.servers", kafkurl},
    { "ssl.ca.location", certlocation},
    { "security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"},
    { "sasl.mechanism", "GSSAPI"},
    { "sasl.username", ""},
    { "sasl.password", ""}
};

using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
{
    var dr = producer.Produce(topicname, jsonmsg).Result;
    Console.WriteLine($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to: {dr.TopicPartitionOffset}");
}
```

Here "jsonmsg" is my actual data(JSON format) as string. How to convert this into Message as expected for this method..? Or Do you have any other method option to use here..? I expect to publish my JSON message along with SSL. Please help.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the magic line:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```